# Preallocating a structure with variables of different names, size and type

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am going to use an algorithm in a `for` loop as an iteration loop. I know that some of the calculations can be done once and the their results can be used as necessary inputs for the algorithm in the `for` loop so in this way there is no need to calculate the same things in each iteration. To do so, I calculate them once and put them in a structure.

I use structure since I have many variables to be kept to be used in the `for` loop and their name and size are different. I put them in the structure with the same name for example:

```
out.A = A;
out.myvector = myvector; 
out.s = s; 
out.Hx_l = Hx_l;
```

and so on. some of them are matrices, some of them cubes or variables with a forth dimension and some of them are cells.

Is there any way to preallocate this kind of structure?

Comment: By any chance do you know the dimensions of A, myvector, s or Hx in advance?

Comment: @brodroll  Yes, I know the dimension of the arrays, but they are different from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialise the structure the following way:

```
out = struct('A',[],'myvector',[],'s',[],'Hx',[]);
```

When you assign the variables afterwards, the structure fields will be already created. Usually the contents are not initialised upfront. Quoting [Loren](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/01/structure-initialization/):

> How important is it to initialize the contents of the struct. Of
>   course it depends on your specifics, but since each field is its own
>   MATLAB array, there is not necessarily a need to initialize them all
>   up front. The key however is to try to not grow either the struct
>   itself or any of its contents incrementally.

Comment: The `A`, `myvector` and `Hx` were some examples. My variable are too many. Should I do what you said for all of them?!

Comment: How many is too many? This is how you would usually initialize a structure. Usually you don't initialise the contents, but it is bad practice to grow the structure fields (variable names) on the run. Loren has a good post on the subject: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/01/structure-initialization/

Comment: Nearly 30 variables! some of them are cell arrays and some of them even 5D arrays. If it really reduce the time I can do it for all variables.  Also I couldn't understand the `nan(3,2)` or `nan(3,1,9)`.

Comment: How about when some of these variables are cells? should I use `{}` instead of `[]` ? I tried this but my struct becomes 0 by 0!

Comment: if you know in advance the size of your arrays (and/or cell arrays), I don't see any harm in pre-allocating them to their final size directly when you define them. For cell arrays you can use `cell(m,n,...)` to preallocate.

Comment: The [] initializes an empty field, acting just like a place holder. It does not matter what you pass to it. It will work for cell, strings, array of cells, anything you assign to it. If you also want to pre-allocate the memory used for these variables, you can fill these fields with dummy variables of the same dimension as the ones you will assign.

Comment: @shalooshaloo If I managed to address your issues and my solution worked for you please consider accepting it as an answer. If not, could you give me some feedback?